# Thymeleaf ..How to pass parameter between one page to another page using th:replace

Tags: thymeleaf

i have a HTMl

```
<th:block th:if="${carePlan != null && 
              carePlan?.getSource().equals(T(com.orsbv.hcs.model.Source).ZORGFLEX)}"
 th:each="domain : ${carePlan?.getNandaDomains()}" th:object="${domain}"
 th:with="evaluationDate=${carePlanHelper.domainEvaluationDate(carePlan,domain)}">
        <div th:replace="client/care-plan/tabs/nanda-domain::div"></div>
</th:block>
```

now i want to pass the domain parameter into nanda-domain.html page. How to achieve this?

Comment: It looks like you may be trying to do this the wrong way round. `th:replace` means "take the content from that other template::fragment (`nanda-domain::div`) and put it here". If so, then you need to convert the HTML in your question into a [fragment](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#including-template-fragments) (without the `th:replace`) - and then add a `th:replace` to nanda-domain.html. See also [this](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#difference-between-thinsert-and-threplace-and-thinclude) note.

Comment: Alternatively, if you are trying to pass a parameter from the above code to `nanda-domain::div`, then take a look at [parameterizable fragment signatures](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#parameterizable-fragment-signatures), which may be what you want. Or, some combination of this and my previous comment.